# Dissatisfaction among or to the

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

His tradition-bound attitude was a constant source of dissatisfaction **among or to** the younger members of the family.

I believe that among is used in a correct form in this sentence. Among is used when referring more than two persons. So , why to is the correct form here because if I mark the answer as among it is wrong.
Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. dissatisfaction among the younger members;

and

> 2. dissatisfaction to the younger members.

The two phrases are both correct but they mean different things:

In #1 there are the younger members that experience the dissatisfaction whereas in #2 somebody else's dissatisfaction is targeted to the younger members.

This said if we used **among** the sentence would make no sense.